# Android Tabcontent overlap with tab

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, tabs

Hi I need some help with Tab. Got some layout advice need to consult.
My current tabcontent seems to overlap with my tab. Anyway to go about preventing that?

[image: Problem with layout]

main.xml

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have put the tabs into your tabcontent. The correct layout is this

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TabWidget />
    <FrameLayout />
</LinearLayout>
```

I guess you are following [this tutorial](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-tabwidget-example.html). The first XML layout there is what yours should look like.